# Binding values of parameters for LIKE operator inside jsonb native Query

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpa, jsonb

I have a problem with declaring and binding parameters values to a native Query using Postgres jsonb syntax using LIKE operator.

It works perfectly fine for = operator, but not for LIKE.

Here's what works for = operator :

```
Query searchQuery = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myJsonBField @> CAST(:param1 as jsonb)", MyEntity.class);
searchQuery.setParameter("param1","{\"attribute\":\"value\"}");
List<MyEntity> queryResult = searchQuery.getResultList();
```

Here's what I am trying to do with LIKE operator

```
Query searchQuery = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myJsonBField --> 'attribute' LIKE :param1", MyEntity.class);
searchQuery.setParameter("param1","'%value%'");
List<MyEntity> queryResult = searchQuery.getResultList();
```

Exception is :

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unknown parameter name : param1; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown parameter name : param1
```

Anyone has an idea how to use parameters with LIKE operator please and patch this up ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the error.

The correct way to do this is :

```
Query searchQuery = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myJsonBField->> 'attribute' LIKE :param1", MyEntity.class);
searchQuery.setParameter("param1","'%value%'");
List<MyEntity> queryResult = searchQuery.getResultList();
```